# How do you recursively replace occurences of a string in an array

Tags: java, recursion, jexl

So consider a class A with two String variables "name" and "value"

class B contains a variable which is Set of A

```
Set<A> allVariables
```

is a set that would look like this

```
A.name="$var1"
A.value = "x+10>2"

A.name="$var2"
A.value="11+y%10==0"

A.name="$var3"
A.value="$var1 && $var2"
```

What I need to do is evaluate these expressions. I'm using jexl for this. I need to iterate through the Set and replace these variable names with their respective values.

In this case, the object with name $var3 needs to be replaced with "x+10>2 && 11+y%10==0"

How do I do this?

Comment: Is it not a issue that you have a set rather than a list? It seem you first need to read your entry 1 and 2 and then evaluate entry 3.

Comment: But this could occur anywhere in the set. There's no definite order of evaluation. Every element in the set may need evaluation

Answer (score 2):

You create 2 Hashmap, `translated` and `toTranslate`.

You parse your Set.

For each A in your Set, you look at value. If value contains any number of `$element` (started by `$` sign), you look for this `$element` in your translated Hashmap keys.

If it's in there, you replace the occurrences of `$element` by the value found in your translated hashmap.

You do this for each different `$element` you found in your A object.

If all `$element` have been translated, you add your object A into the `translated` hashmap (key = name, value = value).

Else, you add it to your `toTranslate` hashmap.

Once all your Set has been parsed, you've got 2 hashmaps.

You create a while loop: while `toTranslate` hashmap is not empty, you take each value, and try to translate the `$element` within it by the ones in your `translate` hashmap.

Be careful, you may end with an infinite loop. One good thing to do would be to make sure that each time you loop on the `toTranslate` hashmap, the numbers of its elements is reduced. If not you're in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it needs to be recursive. I think just this would work:

bool madeReplacement;

do:

bool madeReplacement = false

For each member of the set, X:

For each other member of the set, Y:

Replace all instances of Y.name with Y.value in X.value. If you replaced anything, madeReplacement = true.

while (madeReplacement)

---

Example:

$var1 is value 1

$var2 is value $var1

$var3 is value $var2 + 2

$var3.value contains $var2, replace $var2 with $var1 -> $var1 + 2

$var2.value contains $var1, replace $var1 with 1 -> 1

$var3.value contains $var1, replace $var1 with 1 -> 1 + 2

No value contains any other name, execution finished.

---

Even though we 'evaluated out of order' we eventually got the right answer anyway. However, this algorithm can be O(n^3) in the worst case (imagine if you had n variables that referenced each other in a long chain, and you started the replacement on the wrong end). One way to solve this would be to, when you X.value contains Y.name, first evaluate Y.value recursively (by doing the same loop-over-the-rest-of-the-set). This makes it O(n^2) worst case, so your suspicion that a recursive approach is appropriate may be correct ;)

(I wasn't sure if variable names were guaranteed to start with $, so I wrote it so it would not matter)